# No opencv jar file created in build/bin directory after cmake

Tags: java, python, opencv, ubuntu

I've followed the instructions as mentioned in the official docs here:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

I do not see a jar file in the build/bin directory that I can link to in eclipse. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Really hard to say with this little information. Maybe you forgot to `make install`? Maybe you didn't set your cmake install prefix to anything useful? Maybe you just made a mistake?

Comment: make install is not mentioned in the docs. make -j8 is, and I did execute it.

Comment: @ChrisKitching anything you could make of it? I've been stuck for the past couple of days. Staring to feel helpless.

Comment: I, too, have spent ridiculous amounts of my time dealing with problems to do with OpenCV failing to compile properly. I've never actually used the Java bindings, though, so I'm unlikely to be able to help you overly much: all I can really do is suggest you follow the instructions, which you presumably did :/ . Sorry. OpenCV sucks enormous sweaty monkey balls. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

When you execute the `cmake` command it will result in a list of files to be built under the OpenCV modules. Check there to see whether you find java in it. Otherwise there may be problem with locating your `ANT` or `JNI` location.

Comment: I had the same exact issue. My problem was that I didn't have ANT installed on my linux version. So as soon as I installed it and put the correct path to ANT_EXECUTABLE = "usr/bin/ant" then it worked and generated the .jar and the .so file.